# How would you implement a login in android?

Tags: android

Notice that I've read several posts and I'm still wondering the same, because I'm trying to fulfit this points:

- Login once, "remember forever" until logoff
- Avoid sending password frequently
- Create something like a token.

So here's my main question:
Token is generated randomly, right? So imagine someone uses wireshark and reads this token. Then extranger can use this token faking himself as the real user.

How can I control that?

Thought about sending IMEI and hashing it with token, but it's kinda the same, IMEI can be faked. Thought about sending IP, but if user switches from 3G to Wifi, token would crash, and I dont want that.

Comment: You could always use HTTPS for data exchange.  Then wireshark (or any other packet sniffer) would be useless.

Comment: Login to a distant webserver I guess ? oAuth 2 then. With token stored with the system password manager API.

Comment: @AleksG would happen the same even if https. For example, https would encrypt password `12345` as `R5JiBB$q3`, so some1 sniffing, would read this encrypted password and send this encrypted password directly to the web service, and get access.

Comment: HTTPS doesn't work like this.  With HTTPS, an encrypted tunnel is established for the purpose of communication and the keys would be supplied per encrypted transfer.  The password would need to be encoded with the key specified by the server at the time of request processing; previously encrypted password would most certainly be different from the newly one.

Comment: ok. great. I'd appreciate if you write down it as an answer explaining yourself, so I can accept it as an answer and let other users which may come from google, know what to do.